# What is a proper way to call objective C functions from javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, ios6

I want to know if there is any proper/Documented way to call objective C functions from JavaScript.. ?

I have managed to get it work using the WebView delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

But still I am not feeling convinced with this way, Are anyone of you aware of some other proper/documented workaround for this .. ?

Thanks for your time.